# lintcode permutation-the output is not correct

Tags: python

I tried to do this:

```
def search(rst,list,nums):
   i = 0
   if len(list) == len(nums):
       rst.append(list)
   return
   while i < len(nums):
       if nums[i] not in list:
           list.append(nums[i])
           print i,list,rst
           search(rst,list,nums)
           list.pop()
       i += 1
   return rst

def permutation(nums):
    rst = []
    list = []
    if nums == None or len(nums) == 0:
        return rst
    search(rst,list,nums)
    return rst
```

The final value of `rst` is not correct. Originally the value of `rst` is `[[1,2,3]]`, which is correct, but the value of `rst` was changed to `[[1,3,2],[1,3,2]]`. What's wrong here?

Comment: You never call any of your methods. Please [edit] your question and add the code that calls `search` and/or `permutation`.

Answer (score 0):

after change the rst.append(list) to rst.append(copy.deepcopy(list)), the issue was resolved.